# Elasticsearch rails - can't search for mac extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have setup elastic search rails with the 'elasticsearch-model', 
 'elasticsearch-rails' gems.

I am trying to search for these attachments by their content. It works well when I have an indexed PDF, Word, plain text, or a plefora of other formats. But it does not work when I index a mac format, e.g. .pages, .keynote and .numbers files.

I made sure that mac files get indexed, but it feels like they are not indexed properly. When I look at raw index data for a .word file vs .pages file, they both have their respective attachment fields populated as base64 representation of the document content. It seems like for the mac extensions, however, this base64 representation isn't accurate.

My index model definition:

```
settings index: { number_of_shards: 3 } do
 mappings do
   indexes :filename
   indexes :uploaded_by
   indexes :project_id, index: :not_analyzed
   indexes :attachment, type: 'attachment'
 end
end

def as_indexed_json(options={})
  self.as_json({
    only: [:project_id, :filename, :uploaded_by, :attachment],
    methods: [:attachment]
  })
end
```

My attachment method:

```
def attachment
  if url
    key = url.sub("https://s3.amazonaws.com/#{ENV['BUCKETNAME']}/", "")
    content = AWS.s3.buckets[ENV['BUCKETNAME']].objects[key].read

    Base64.encode64(content)
  end
end
```

The file first gets uploaded to s3 (since client side sends it there directly), then read by the server from s3 to get indexed. this is a proof of concept code only, future dev will upload from client to server, index, then upload to s3, then delete from server.

E.S version: "1.7.1",
Lucene version: "4.10.4"

Comment: Update: found out that Tika 0.9 has support for iWork formats, however, Tike 1.4 does not. Seems like support dropped around the 1.0 version. Why? What happened? Can I bring this support back?